# Assign static variable inside Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to create a static variable inside class like below,

```
public class ClassEnLanguage
{
  public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

this is no problem work fine even I can access this from other class, now I want to add values into dictionary object without using any method. like,

```
public class ClassEnLanguage
{
 public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("somekey1","someValue1");
    dictionary.Add("somekey2","someValue2");
}
```

Like in Java we can do like that,

```
public class ClassLanguageEn {
     public static HashMap labels = new HashMap();
        static {        
            labels.put("somekey1","someValue1");
            labels.put("somekey2","someValue2");
               }
}
```

and we can access this variable using `ClassLanguageEn.labels (Classname.VariableName)`.

Now my question is will it possible to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type initializer, or [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx), like this:

```
public class ClassEnLanguage
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    static ClassEnLanguage()
    {
        dictionary.Add("somekey1","someValue1");
        dictionary.Add("somekey2","someValue2");
    }
}
```

Note that you can also use a dictionary initializer like this:

```
public class ClassEnLanguage
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "somekey1", "someValue1" },
            { "somekey2", "someValue2" }
        };
}
```

Comment: thanks for urgent reply @p.s.w.g
really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Yes, a collection initializer seems natural here (the second example).